# Microsoft.NETCORE.app dependency not resolved in VS 2015

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am having issues with Visual Studio 2015 that when I create a new CORE 1.0 project the references show an error that says that .NETCoreApp cannot be resolved. When I open the project.json file Microsoft.NETCore.App is underlined and the solution to fix it is to "sort properties".

I have installed VS 2015 update 3 and also .net core tools preview 2.

The sort properties does work but I also notice that intelisense is broken in the projects.json file when trying to add dependencies.

I am a newbie to .net and VS2015 and I am trying to work out of books and tutorials.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run `dotnet restore` on the terminal in the project folder?

Comment: Doing dotnet restore just runs successfully but doesn't resolve the unresolved dependency errors. I have the following listed in solution explorer under
NU1001 The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.
NU1001 The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.
NU1001 The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.
NU1001 The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.
NU1001 The dependency Microsoft.NETCore.App >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.

Comment: I also discovered if I open the project.json file and save it without modifications it fixes the dependency warnings and it does it without running dotnet restore.
Still doesn't fix intellisense however.

Comment: Resolved....

I failed to add that this was a Windows 10 VM running in parallels on MAC and the projects directory was defaulted to the MAC home drive so it looked like a UNC share "\\MAC\Home\" etc. Once I changed to saving to a letter drive everything looked good. 

Thanks to a coworker that started remembering that he had the same issue a long time ago. 

Thanks Nate for trying to help.

Answer (score 4):

Resolved.... I failed to add that this was a Windows 10 VM running in parallels on MAC and the projects directory was defaulted to the MAC home drive so it looked like a UNC share "\MAC\Home\" etc. Once I changed to saving to a letter drive everything looked good. Thanks to a coworker that started remembering that he had the same issue a long time ago. Thanks Nate for trying to help.

Comment: This saved me! You should mark it as the accepted answer as clearly it did resolved your issue! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved...

Entered tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages For Solution

And uninstalled Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.ISSIntegration then reinstalled it.

It automatically got all the other dependencies here

"dependencies": { "Microsoft.NETCore.App": { "version": "1.0.1", "type": "platform" }, "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1", "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0" },

Then Restarted Visual Studio and solution build succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete the following files from your solution: `project.fragment.lock.json` and `project.lock.json` and the errors will resolve itself.