# Microsoft.netcore.app Dependency unable to be restored in VS 2015 (not resolved)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, project.json

I am  a newbie to ASP.net core and trying to work on my tutorials.
I am creating a .net core project and upon creation errors in package restore occur, I have already installed VS 2015 update 3 and also .net core tools preview 2. The project.json file shows underlines beneath the Microsoft.netcore.app and fixing this offers "sort properties" solution which haven't worked out

I am using a windows VM on a mac which is causing problems in restoring the packages into the project.

I have already found a similar question over here

[Microsoft.NETCORE.app dependency not resolved in VS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322491/microsoft-netcore-app-dependency-not-resolved-in-vs-2015/42464006#42464006)

but I havn't quit understood the resolution

Comment: Although this isn't an answer to your question, why don't you Visual Studio for Mac Preview? I've created a couple core applications on it and it works fairly well.

Comment: Hello, I thought about it and read a bit some architecture and modeling tools aren't supported but on the enterprise version. And I am oblijed with some team services software that are non functional but on windows. Thank you hope that would have solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved...

Entered tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages For Solution

And uninstalled Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.ISSIntegration 
then reinstalled it.

It automatically got all the other dependencies here

"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0"
  },

Then Restarted Visual Studio and solution build succeeded.